# KDB/Q-sql Dynamic Grouping and con-canting columns in output

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase, qsqlquerymodel

I have a table where I have to perform group by on dynamic columns and perform aggregation, result will be column values concatenating group-by tables and aggregations on col supplied by users.

For example :

```
g1  g2  g3  g4  col1    col2
A   D   F   H   10      20
A   E   G   I   11      21
B   D   G   J   12      22
B   E   F   L   13      23
C   D   F   M   14      24
C   D   G   M   15      25
```

and if I need to perform group by g1,g2,g4 and avg aggregation on col1 output should be like this

```
    filed           val
Avg[A-D-H-col1]    10.0
Avg[A-E-I-col1]    11.0
Avg[B-D-J-col1]    12.0
Avg[B-E-L-col1]    13.0
Avg[C-D-M-col1]    14.5
```

I am able to perform this if my group by columns are fixed using q-sql

```
t:([]g1:`A`A`B`B`C`C;g2:`D`E`D`E`D`D;g3:`F`G`G`F`F`G;g4:`H`I`J`L`M`M;col1:10 11 12 13 14 15;col2:20 21 22 23 24 25)

select filed:first ("Avg[",/:(({"-" sv x} each string (g1,'g2,'g4)),\:"-col1]")),val: avg col1 by g1,g2,g4 from t
```

I want to use functional query for the same , means I want a function which take list of group by columns, aggregation to perform and col name andtable name as input and output like above query. I can perform group by easily using dynamic columns but not able to con-cat in fields. function signature will be something like this

**fun{[glist; agg;  col,t] .. ;... }[`g1`g2`g4;`avg;`col1,`t]**

Please help me to make above query as dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try following function:

```
specialGroup: {[glist;agg;col;table]

    res: ?[table;();{x!x}glist; enlist[`val]!enlist(agg;col)];
    aggname: string agg;
    aggname: upper[1#aggname], 1_aggname;
    res: ![res;();0b;enlist[`filed]!enlist({(y,"["),/:("-"sv/:string flip x),\:"]"};enlist,glist,enlist[enlist col];aggname)];
    res
};

specialGroup[`g1`g2`g4;avg;`col1;t]
```

`specialGroup` aggregates values into `val` column first. And populates `filed` column after grouping. This helps to avoid generating `filed` duplicates and selecting first of them.

Comment: Thank you @Anton  for saving my day,   this was what i needed, can you help me also to add "Avg[" added in starting should be dynamic, like if aggregation is min , then it should be  min[[A-D-H-col1] , not fixed one.

Comment: You are welcome @sam. I updated above solution. Aggregation function is converted to string `string agg` and passed into function which generates `filed` values as second parameter

Comment: If `aggname` doesn't have to be capitalised, remove rows with `aggname` and pass `string agg` instead of `aggname` into the function

Answer (score 0):

If you modify Anton's code to this it will change the output dynamically

```
specialGroup: {[glist;agg;col;table]
           res: ?[table;();{x!x}glist; enlist[`val]!enlist(agg;col)];
           res: ![res;();0b;enlist[`filed]!enlist({(@[string[y];0;upper],"["),/:("-"sv/:string flip x),\:"]"}[;agg];enlist,glist,enlist[enlist col])];
           res
    };
```

As the part of the code that made that string was inside another function you need to pass the agg parameter to the inner function.